# How to do point-wise categorical crossentropy loss in Keras?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, cross-entropy, loss-function

I have a network that produces a 4D output tensor where the value at each position in spatial dimensions (~pixel) is to be interpreted as the class probabilities for that position.  In other words, the output is `(num_batches, height, width, num_classes)`.  I have labels of the same size where the real class is coded as one-hot.  I would like to calculate the `categorical-crossentropy` loss using this.

**Problem #1:** The `K.softmax` function expects a `2D` tensor `(num_batches, num_classes)`

**Problem #2**: I'm not sure how the losses from each position should be combined.  Is it correct to `reshape` the tensor to `(num_batches * height * width, num_classes)` and then calling `K.categorical_crossentropy` on that?  Or rather, call `K.categorical_crossentropy(num_batches, num_classes)` height*width times and average the results?

Comment: Which backend do you use?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko I use TensorFlow - could either use the Keras backend api or TF's own functions, either is fine.  Thanks!

Comment: I've answered your question :-)

Comment: Dude - you need to check out our answers, because in other way you the first answer (this one you got before you raised a bounty) would win :)

Answer (score 8):

Found [this issue](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/1169) to confirm my intuition.

In short : the softmax will take 2D or 3D inputs. If they are 3D keras will assume a shape like this (samples, timedimension, numclasses) and apply the softmax on the last one.  For some weird reasons, it doesnt do that for 4D tensors.

Solution : reshape your output to a sequence of pixels

```
reshaped_output = Reshape((height*width, num_classes))(output_tensor)
```

Then apply your softmax

```
new_output = Activation('softmax')(reshaped_output)
```

And then either you reshape your target tensors to 2D or you just reshape that last layer into (width, height, num_classes).

Otherwise, something I would try if I wasn't on my phone right now is to use a `TimeDistributed(Activation('softmax'))`. But no idea if that would work... will try later

I hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 2):

Just flatten the output to a 2D tensor of size `(num_batches, height * width * num_classes)`. You can do this with the `Flatten` layer. Ensure that your `y` is flattened the same way (normally calling `y = y.reshape((num_batches, height * width * num_classes))` is enough).

For your second question, using categorical crossentropy over all `width*height` predictions is essentially the same as averaging the categorical crossentropy for each `width*height` predictions (by the definition of categorical crossentropy).

Comment: Thanks!  I'm confused by (num_batches, height * width * num_classes) though.  Isn't that essentially calculating cross-entropy as though there were num_batches samples with height * width * num_classes classes each?  I'm pretty sure I want each point to be counted as a separate sample, isn't that the same as reshaping to (num_batches * height * width, num_classes)?  Please let me know if the two are equivalent math-wise.

Comment: Sorry, categorical crossentropy alone will be essentially the same math-wise. But using it together with softmax will not be the same math-wise because the output is normalized, which is a miss in my answer. I don't think it's possible to change the batch-size of the input midpoint in the model. The best way is probably to make a work-around and implement your own softmax activation function that normalizes the output for each of the `height * width` cells.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm still confused on how to translate that to working code, could you have a shot at that?  I started a bounty :)

Answer (score 2):

You could also not `reshape` anything and define both `softmax` and `loss` on your own. Here is `softmax` which is applied to the last input dimension (like in `tf` backend):

```
def image_softmax(input):
    label_dim = -1
    d = K.exp(input - K.max(input, axis=label_dim, keepdims=True))
    return d / K.sum(d, axis=label_dim, keepdims=True)
```

and here you have `loss` (there is no need to reshape anything):

```
__EPS = 1e-5
def image_categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred):
    y_pred = K.clip(y_pred, __EPS, 1 - __EPS)
    return -K.mean(y_true * K.log(y_pred) + (1 - y_true) * K.log(1 - y_pred))
```

No further reshapes need.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that now you can simply do `softmax` activation on the last `Conv2D` layer and then specify `categorical_crossentropy` loss and train on the image without any reshaping tricks or any new loss function. I've tried overfitting with a dummy dataset and it works well. Try it ~ !

```py
inp = keras.Input(...)
# define your model here
out = keras.layers.Conv2D(classes, (1, 1), activation='softmax') (...)
model = keras.Model(inputs=[inp], outputs=[out], name='unet')
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                      optimizer='adam',
                      metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(tensor4d, tensor4d)
```

You can also compile using `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` and then train with output of shape `(samples, height, width)` where each pixel in the output corresponds to a class label: `model.fit(tensor4d, tensor3d)`

The idea is that `softmax` and `categorical_crossentropy` will be applied to the last axis (you can check `keras.backend.softmax` and `keras.backend.categorical_crossentropy` doc).

PS. I use `keras` from `tensorflow.keras` (tensorflow 2)

Update: I have trained on my real dataset and it is working as well.