# What should the output layer of my CNN look like?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I am running a model to detect a few interesting features in an image. I have a set of images measuring 600x200 px. These images have features such as rock fragments that I would like to identify. Imagine a (4x12) grid overlayed on the image I can produce annotations manually using an annotator tool such as `((4,9), (3,10), (3,11), (3,12))` to identify the interesting cells in the image. I can build a CNN model with Keras with the input as a grayscale image. But how should I encode the output. One way that seems intuitive to me is to treat it as a sparse matrix of shape `(12,4,1)` and only the interesting cells have 1 while others have 0.

- Is there a better way to encode the outputs?
- What should be the activation function on the last layer be? I am using ReLU for the hidden layers.
- What should the loss function be? Will `mean_squared_error` work?

Comment: why dont you split up your image and classify every gridfield seperatly with a "smaller network (4*12)"

Comment: These images are flattened from a circular borehole. So I am interested in sinusoidal patterns to identify interesting geological features as opposed to other rock features that look similar but are not sinusoidal.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is really similiar to both detection and segmentation problems (you can read about it e.g. [here](https://sigmoidal.io/dl-computer-vision-beyond-classification/). The approach you proposed is reasonable because in both detection and segmentation tasks computing the feature map you proposed is an usual part of training pipeline. However - there are several problem you might come across:

- **memory issues**: you need to either deal with sparse tensors or use generators in order to deal with memory problems,
- **loss and activation**: loss and activation for segmentation are currently not supported by Keras API so you need to implement it on your own. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43033436/how-to-do-point-wise-categorical-crossentropy-loss-in-keras/43195222#43195222) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42118821/cross-entropy-loss-for-semantic-segmentation-keras) you can find an examples on how to tackle this problem.

In case of detection only (not classification of this points) I would advice you to use `sigmoid` and `binary_crossentropy`. In case of classification `softmax` and `categorical_crossentropy`.

Of course - there are other ways on how to tackle this problem. One could solve it as a regression where you need to predict the pixels where there is something interesting. But dealing with varying input in `Keras` is rather cumbersome.